# Why df.rdd.getNumPartitions() return number of partitions different than F.spark_partition_id() reports?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here's the code that simply just creates 2 data frames and join them. At the end you can see the 2 functions call reporting contradicted results on the number of partitions:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold","-1")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled","false")
 
#create a one column(column name: value) DF
#with 100k elements with 99% of the value 
#being 1 and 1% being 0
df_skew = spark.createDataFrame([0] * 100000,
  IntegerType()).withColumn("key",
  when(rand()<0.01,0).otherwise(1))

#create a DF with 100 elements with 2 columns
#(column name: value,size)
df_small = spark.createDataFrame([i for i in 
  range(100)],IntegerType())  \
  .withColumn("size", when(rand()<0.1, 
  "small").otherwise("large")).repartition(3)

#directly join 2 data frames, note the 
#partition number reported below
#(spark_partition_id is a build-in function 
#that'll will tell what partition each row is 
#in so we can count the number of all the 
#partitions by using a groupBy/count
df_joined=df_skew.join(df_small,"value",
  "inner").select(df_skew.value,df_skew.key,
  df_small.size)
print("partitionId count on df_joined:")
df_joined.withColumn("partitionId",
  spark_partition_id()).groupBy("partitionId")
  .count().show()
print("df_joined getNumPartitions() :" , 
  df_joined.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Output: (as you can see from above code, getNumPartitions says there are 200 partitions, yet the function spark_partition_id only reports one partition on the same data frame(partitionId:191), can anyone explain this. Thank you very much. Spark version is 3.0.

```
partitionId count on df_joined:
+-----------+------+
|partitionId| count|
+-----------+------+
|        191|100000|
+-----------+------+

df_joined getNumPartitions() : 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Why number of partitions are different?

**This is because of the setting `"spark.sql.adaptive.enabled"`**. Since you have turned this option off spark will no longer be able to optimize the shuffle partitions during the `join`. By default spark creates `200` shuffle partitions which is also the default value of option `"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"`. So for example if you were to set the value of this option to `100` spark will create `100` partitions after `join`.

The most important thing here is that although the number of partitions is `200` most of the partitions are empty. You can verify this by executing the following code

```
>>> set(map(len, df_joined.rdd.glom().collect()))
{0, 100000}
```

As you can see from the above output except for one partition rest of the partitions are empty. Now coming back to the output of grouping by `F.spark_partition_id` and counting the rows as its evident from the above output that all the data is only in one partition hence the aggregation reports `100000` rows in partition ID `191`.

Comment: I turned the AQE to true and re-run the code, then both functions return the number of partitions very close. Thank you very much Shubham for the insights ! I accepted the answer.

Comment: Happy coding @Jerry ~